# Searching for a specified word in the file opened in VI editor

Tags: vim, editor

Please tell me how to search for a specifig word if the file is opened in VI Editor. I know we can do it by using /word_to_be_search but it will not do the exact search for the word.

```
Example
/sachin will searches for sachin_server, sachin_client and not only sachin
```

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Try instead:

```
/\<word\>
```

the `\<` and `\>` match word boundaries.

Comment: ...and in Vim, you can ":set iskeyword" to define the characters considered part of a "word"

Answer (score 4):

```
/\<sachin\>
```

`\<` is the beginning of word, and `\>` is the end of word marker.

Answer (score -1):

do this:

/\

Comment: It wont work as it will only search for words starting with the pattern to be searched